# horizontal label center and graph bar center in ssrs chart

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bar-chart, ssrs-2008-r2

I have simple ssrs chart. Currently my chart looks like below.

[image]

but I want to move horizontal labels and bars in center. It should look like below

[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Really late to this and you may have worked it out already but...

You can do this using the "Interval Offset" property under the MajorTickMarks menu.

Select the axis and expand the menu. I am not sure what your dataset looks like but changing the property to 0.5 did the trick when I just tested.